# css how to float or display two elements of unknown widths next to each other inside a div of unknown width

Tags: css

I have an img and a block of text that need to be displayed next to each other. The text should not wrap below the image if it extends beyond it vertically. The img is always 50px but the text needs to flow to fit the remaining width of the container, which is subsequently set to the width of the user's browser. How do I do this?

so essentially:

```
<div> <!--width is 100% of browser-->
<img/> <!--width is 48px-->
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p><!--width is unknown. Should show up next to img -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your wrapping div should get `overflow: hidden` or some kind of clearfix.

```
img {
    float: left;
}
```

**EDIT:** Don't let the text go below the image:

```
p {
    margin-left: 48px;  
}
```

Small example: http://jsfiddle.net/AJkRu/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">


.left
{
 float:left;
 width:50px;
}

.right
{
float:right;
width:400px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width: 500px;">

<div class="left">
<img src="logocss.gif"  />
</div>

<div class="right">
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This. is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This. is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text
</div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I know how to float elements, but I don't want the text to ever go directly below the image.

Answer (score 0):

Is this only for the image? Why all the div's and extra css?

CSS

```
p{padding-left:50px;}   
p img{float:left;margin-left:-50px;}
```

HTML

```
<p><img /> ... </p>
```

Comment: I don't want the text to ever wrap below the image

Comment: Like so http://jsfiddle.net/AJkRu/3/? Then add a margin-right to the `p` like I postet in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the image will never be wider than 48-50px you can give that a fixed width, or put it inside a div with a fixed width?

```
div img {
width:48px;
float:left;
}
```

Then the P will wrap around it perfectly, be sure to add some right and bottom margins if that's the case.

And give the wrapper div (the full width) some form of clearfix, or even just `clear:both` I suppose.

```
div {
clear:both;
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can also do it using tables

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img/>this is the image</td>
<td><p>ur text here</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```